# URL not being assigned correctly on JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have my array of objects. These are the first two elements of the array.
The facebookImage has the correct url of the image.

```
0: Object
categoria: "Radio station"
ciudad: "San Pedro Sula"
facebookId: "146335797628"
facebookImage: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10003180_775934785757747_2192426716601201507_n.jpg?oh=52b844b5e1cfb4dece7a6a913b8b199b&oe=54ED0B04&__gda__=1420510306_7182120c9820f84ea2c3e32d2ec78391"
likes: 1823125
link: "https://www.facebook.com/RadioactivaHN
nombre: "RADIO ACTIVA 99.7 FM LA MERA YEMA"

__proto__: 
Object1: Object
categoria: "Radio station"
ciudad: "Utila"
facebookId: "134107033277316"
facebookImage: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/v/t1.0-1/c6.0.50.50/p50x50/10394038_841172835904062_5626565660847326671_n.jpg?oh=c441ade9229e07793c15f028afaae7b2&oe=54F8A2D1&__gda__=1421372327_3336119134db5365a657a76ea051f5df"
likes: 1519597
link: "https://www.facebook.com/Musiquera"
nombre: "MUSIQUERA TU MEJOR COMPAÑERA"
```

The issue comes, when I tried to a console.log(JSON.stringify(ARRAY)). The url gets cut and I lost completely the url. How can I solve this issue?

```
[
    {
        "facebookId": "146335797628",
        "likes": 1823125,
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/RadioactivaHN",
        "nombre": "RADIO ACTIVA 99.7 FM LA MERA YEMA",
        "ciudad": "San Pedro Sula",
        "categoria": "Radio station",
        "facebookImage": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10003…913b8b199b&oe=54ED0B04&__gda__=1420510306_7182120c9820f84ea2c3e32d2ec78391"
    },
    {
        "facebookId": "134107033277316",
        "likes": 1519597,
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Musiquera",
        "nombre": "MUSIQUERA TU MEJOR COMPAÑERA",
        "ciudad": "Utila",
        "categoria": "Radio station",
        "facebookImage": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/v/t1.0-1/c6.0.50.50/p…28afaae7b2&oe=54F8A2D1&__gda__=1421372327_3336119134db5365a657a76ea051f5df"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is console.log() is truncating the long url string, you can use console.dir() or you can disable the truncation by going to about:config and set extensions.firebug.stringCropLength to 0.